# Different output observed in IE8 and IE11 for same HTML file

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

when I open the below html code in  ie8 and ie11  the output is different.

```
<div style="left: 0; top: 0; color: EAE6F1; z-index: 5; position: hidden; " id="Screen147">


<img style="left: 0; top: 2; z-index: 2; position: absolute; width: 1280; height: 1020; " id="item1" src="Desert.jpg" border="0"/>

<div style="left: 608; top: 563; background-color: FFFFFF; color: 000000; z-index: 2; position: absolute; font-family:  'Arial'; font-size: 31px; layout-grid: both fixed 51px 32px; white-space: nowrap; " id="item2">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>

<div style="left: 608; top: 614; background-color: FFFFFF; color: 000000; z-index: 3; position: absolute; font-family:  'Arial'; font-size: 31px; layout-grid: both fixed 51px 32px; white-space: nowrap; " id="item3">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>

<div style="left: 608; top: 665; background-color: FFFFFF; color: 000000; z-index: 4; position: absolute; font-family:  'Arial'; font-size: 31px; layout-grid: both fixed 51px 32px; white-space: nowrap; " id="item4">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

I want to display a white block in the image.
but when run in IE8 the white block appears bigger as compared to when displayed in IE11. 
wanted to attach the images but lacked the reputation.

I wanted to know why is this behaviour and if the code is same then the output should also be the same. can anyone help me to understand this behaviour?

thank you very much in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML output depends upon your browser veersion. Many features of HTML5 and CSS3 are not supported in some of the old browsers. Have a look at the features supported by some famous browsers.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp

Comment: thanks for your reply, but here in my case it was supported by IE8 as well as IE11 but the difference i am getting is in the sizes of both the white box.
can you suggest what could be the reason for it being different?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is the best way to measure / set the size of something by using font and (non breaking) spaces.
That being said, you should use the [`width`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp)/[`height`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp) properties, and the [units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

Also take a look at the [usage of CSS3's `box-sizing` property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp).